# Is there a git or bash way to pull multple git repos other than moving to each directory?

Tags: bash, git

I wrote this (brute force) script bring multiple repos up to date.

```
for app in $(/bin/ls  -d $@)
do
  cd $app
  pwd
  git pull
  cd ..;
done
```

Is there a simpler way I can do this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could at least simplify the script:

1. [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
2. Use [`for x` instead of `for x in "$@"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs)
3. Use a [subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping) to [avoid `cd`-ing out](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2103)

And to avoid bugs:

1. [Quote your args](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)
2. Use `--` on `cd` to avoid arguments being interpreted as options
3. [Skip the loop if `cd` fails](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2164)

```
for app; do
    (
        cd -- "$app" || continue
        pwd
        git pull
    )
done
```

BTW [Shellchek](https://shellcheck.net) is a great resource for debugging shell scripts. I got most of these tips there.

Comment: This is quite trivial, but I prefer the `for app do` syntax (no semicolon) as some truly ancient not-bash shells didn't like the semicolon there, and in any case it's one character shorter :-)